# How to position a node relatively to another node with different distances on the two axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a node `x` and another one `y` I want to put `2cm` above and `3cm` right of `x`.
Right now when I face this situation I proceed in two steps by declaring a `dummy` empty node:

```
\node (x) {x};
\node[above of=x,node distance=2cm] (dummy) {};
\node[right of=dummy,node distance=3cm] (y) {y};
```

This works but it is tedious and rather clumsy.
Is there a cleaner way to do that?

Comment: `\node[above right=2cm and 3cm of x] (y) {$y$};`

Comment: works like a charm. many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}


\node[circle, draw=black] (x) {$x$};

\node[circle, draw=black, above right=2cm and 3cm of x] (z) {$z$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```